# Replacing dead node, got RuntimeException: "Unable to gossip with any peers"

Tags: cassandra

While Replacing node with dead node getting below error.
Can you please let me know the resolution.

```
-bash-4.2$ cassandra
-bash-4.2$ OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: If the number of processors is expected to increase from one, then you should configure the number of parallel GC threads appropriately using -XX:ParallelGCThreads=N
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.deserializeLargeSubset (Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataInputPlus;Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubset (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;ILorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/Columns$Serializer.serializeLargeSubsetSize (Ljava/util/Collection;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/Columns;I)I
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/AbstractCommitLogSegmentManager.advanceAllocatingFrom (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/commitlog/CommitLogSegment;)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/BaseIterator.tryGetMoreContents ()Z
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stop ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/db/transform/StoppingTransformation.stopInPartition ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.doFlush (I)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeExcessSlow ()V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/BufferedDataOutputStreamPlus.writeSlow (JI)V
CompilerOracle: dontinline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/RebufferingInputStream.readPrimitiveSlowly (I)J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/db/rows/UnfilteredSerializer.serializeRowBody (Lorg/apache/cassandra/db/rows/Row;ILorg/apache/cassandra/db/SerializationHeader;Lorg/apache/cassandra/io/util/DataOutputPlus;)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/Memory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/io/util/SafeMemory.checkBounds (JJ)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.selectBoundary (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;II)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering.strictnessOfLessThan (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/AsymmetricOrdering/Op;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.indexes (Lorg/apache/cassandra/utils/IFilter/FilterKey;)[J
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/BloomFilter.setIndexes (JJIJ[J)V
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;[B)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compare ([BLjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/ByteBufferUtil.compareUnsigned (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/lang/Object;JI)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/lang/Object;JILjava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/FastByteOperations$UnsafeOperations.compareTo (Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;Ljava/nio/ByteBuffer;)I
CompilerOracle: inline org/apache/cassandra/utils/vint/VIntCoding.encodeVInt (JI)[B
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:35,695 YamlConfigurationLoader.java:93 - Configuration location: file:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,249 Config.java:555 - Node configuration:[allocate_tokens_for_keyspace=null; allow_extra_insecure_udfs=false; allow_insecure_udfs=false; authenticator=AllowAllAuthenticator; authorizer=AllowAllAuthorizer; auto_bootstrap=true; auto_snapshot=true; back_pressure_enabled=false; back_pressure_strategy=org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}; batch_size_fail_threshold_in_kb=50; batch_size_warn_threshold_in_kb=5; batchlog_replay_throttle_in_kb=1024; broadcast_address=null; broadcast_rpc_address=null; buffer_pool_use_heap_if_exhausted=true; cache_load_timeout_seconds=30; cas_contention_timeout_in_ms=1000; cdc_enabled=false; cdc_free_space_check_interval_ms=250; cdc_raw_directory=/apps/opt/cassandra/data/cdc_raw; cdc_total_space_in_mb=0; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_compaction=true; check_for_duplicate_rows_during_reads=true; client_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; cluster_name=Test Cluster; column_index_cache_size_in_kb=2; column_index_size_in_kb=64; commit_failure_policy=stop; commitlog_compression=null; commitlog_directory=/apps/opt/cassandra/data/commitlogs; commitlog_max_compression_buffers_in_pool=3; commitlog_periodic_queue_size=-1; commitlog_segment_size_in_mb=32; commitlog_sync=periodic; commitlog_sync_batch_window_in_ms=NaN; commitlog_sync_period_in_ms=10000; commitlog_total_space_in_mb=null; compaction_large_partition_warning_threshold_mb=100; compaction_throughput_mb_per_sec=16; concurrent_compactors=null; concurrent_counter_writes=32; concurrent_materialized_view_writes=32; concurrent_reads=32; concurrent_replicates=null; concurrent_writes=32; counter_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; counter_cache_save_period=7200; counter_cache_size_in_mb=null; counter_write_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; credentials_cache_max_entries=1000; credentials_update_interval_in_ms=-1; credentials_validity_in_ms=2000; cross_node_timeout=false; data_file_directories=[Ljava.lang.String;@4278a03f; disk_access_mode=auto; disk_failure_policy=stop; disk_optimization_estimate_percentile=0.95; disk_optimization_page_cross_chance=0.1; disk_optimization_strategy=ssd; dynamic_snitch=true; dynamic_snitch_badness_threshold=0.1; dynamic_snitch_reset_interval_in_ms=600000; dynamic_snitch_update_interval_in_ms=100; enable_drop_compact_storage=false; enable_materialized_views=true; enable_sasi_indexes=true; enable_scripted_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions=false; enable_user_defined_functions_threads=true; encryption_options=<REDACTED>; endpoint_snitch=GossipingPropertyFileSnitch; file_cache_round_up=null; file_cache_size_in_mb=null; force_new_prepared_statement_behaviour=false; gc_log_threshold_in_ms=200; gc_warn_threshold_in_ms=1000; hinted_handoff_disabled_datacenters=[]; hinted_handoff_enabled=true; hinted_handoff_throttle_in_kb=1024; hints_compression=null; hints_directory=/apps/opt/cassandra/data/hints; hints_flush_period_in_ms=10000; incremental_backups=false; index_interval=null; index_summary_capacity_in_mb=null; index_summary_resize_interval_in_minutes=60; initial_token=null; inter_dc_stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; inter_dc_tcp_nodelay=false; internode_authenticator=null; internode_compression=dc; internode_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=0; internode_send_buff_size_in_bytes=0; key_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; key_cache_save_period=14400; key_cache_size_in_mb=null; listen_address=null; listen_interface=eth0; listen_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; listen_on_broadcast_address=false; max_hint_window_in_ms=10800000; max_hints_delivery_threads=2; max_hints_file_size_in_mb=128; max_mutation_size_in_kb=null; max_streaming_retries=3; max_value_size_in_mb=256; memtable_allocation_type=heap_buffers; memtable_cleanup_threshold=null; memtable_flush_writers=0; memtable_heap_space_in_mb=null; memtable_offheap_space_in_mb=null; min_free_space_per_drive_in_mb=50; native_transport_flush_in_batches_legacy=true; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_connections_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes=-1; native_transport_max_concurrent_requests_in_bytes_per_ip=-1; native_transport_max_frame_size_in_mb=256; native_transport_max_negotiable_protocol_version=-2147483648; native_transport_max_threads=128; native_transport_port=9042; native_transport_port_ssl=null; num_tokens=16; otc_backlog_expiration_interval_ms=200; otc_coalescing_enough_coalesced_messages=8; otc_coalescing_strategy=DISABLED; otc_coalescing_window_us=200; partitioner=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner; permissions_cache_max_entries=1000; permissions_update_interval_in_ms=-1; permissions_validity_in_ms=2000; phi_convict_threshold=8.0; prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; range_request_timeout_in_ms=10000; read_request_timeout_in_ms=5000; repair_session_max_tree_depth=18; request_scheduler=org.apache.cassandra.scheduler.NoScheduler; request_scheduler_id=null; request_scheduler_options=null; request_timeout_in_ms=10000; role_manager=CassandraRoleManager; roles_cache_max_entries=1000; roles_update_interval_in_ms=-1; roles_validity_in_ms=2000; row_cache_class_name=org.apache.cassandra.cache.OHCProvider; row_cache_keys_to_save=2147483647; row_cache_save_period=0; row_cache_size_in_mb=0; rpc_address=null; rpc_interface=eth0; rpc_interface_prefer_ipv6=false; rpc_keepalive=true; rpc_listen_backlog=50; rpc_max_threads=2147483647; rpc_min_threads=16; rpc_port=9160; rpc_recv_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_send_buff_size_in_bytes=null; rpc_server_type=sync; saved_caches_directory=/apps/opt/cassandra/data/saved_caches; seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=172.31.86.170}; server_encryption_options=<REDACTED>; slow_query_log_timeout_in_ms=500; snapshot_before_compaction=false; snapshot_on_duplicate_row_detection=false; ssl_storage_port=7001; sstable_preemptive_open_interval_in_mb=50; start_native_transport=true; start_rpc=false; storage_port=7000; stream_throughput_outbound_megabits_per_sec=200; streaming_keep_alive_period_in_secs=300; streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms=86400000; thrift_framed_transport_size_in_mb=15; thrift_max_message_length_in_mb=16; thrift_prepared_statements_cache_size_mb=null; tombstone_failure_threshold=100000; tombstone_warn_threshold=1000; tracetype_query_ttl=86400; tracetype_repair_ttl=604800; transparent_data_encryption_options=org.apache.cassandra.config.TransparentDataEncryptionOptions@147ed70f; trickle_fsync=false; trickle_fsync_interval_in_kb=10240; truncate_request_timeout_in_ms=60000; unlogged_batch_across_partitions_warn_threshold=10; user_defined_function_fail_timeout=1500; user_defined_function_warn_timeout=500; user_function_timeout_policy=die; windows_timer_interval=1; write_request_timeout_in_ms=2000]
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,250 DatabaseDescriptor.java:381 - DiskAccessMode 'auto' determined to be mmap, indexAccessMode is mmap
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,251 DatabaseDescriptor.java:439 - Global memtable on-heap threshold is enabled at 242MB
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,251 DatabaseDescriptor.java:443 - Global memtable off-heap threshold is enabled at 242MB
WARN  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,256 DatabaseDescriptor.java:503 - Small commitlog volume detected at /apps/opt/cassandra/data/commitlogs; setting commitlog_total_space_in_mb to 2044.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,257 DatabaseDescriptor.java:530 - Small cdc volume detected at /apps/opt/cassandra/data/cdc_raw; setting cdc_total_space_in_mb to 1022.  You can override this in cassandra.yaml
WARN  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,443 DatabaseDescriptor.java:579 - Only 6.071GiB free across all data volumes. Consider adding more capacity to your cluster or removing obsolete snapshots
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,470 RateBasedBackPressure.java:123 - Initialized back-pressure with high ratio: 0.9, factor: 5, flow: FAST, window size: 2000.
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,471 DatabaseDescriptor.java:781 - Back-pressure is disabled with strategy org.apache.cassandra.net.RateBasedBackPressure{high_ratio=0.9, factor=5, flow=FAST}.
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,686 GossipingPropertyFileSnitch.java:64 - Loaded cassandra-topology.properties for compatibility
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,940 JMXServerUtils.java:253 - Configured JMX server at: service:jmx:rmi://127.0.0.1/jndi/rmi://127.0.0.1:7199/jmxrmi
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,948 CassandraDaemon.java:490 - Hostname: ip-172-31-88-213.ec2.internal
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,957 CassandraDaemon.java:497 - JVM vendor/version: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_372
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,962 CassandraDaemon.java:498 - Heap size: 970.000MiB/970.000MiB
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,962 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Code Cache Non-heap memory: init = 2555904(2496K) used = 4556224(4449K) committed = 4587520(4480K) max = 251658240(245760K)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,969 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Metaspace Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 22798512(22264K) committed = 23298048(22752K) max = -1(-1K)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,970 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Compressed Class Space Non-heap memory: init = 0(0K) used = 2604048(2543K) committed = 2830336(2764K) max = 1073741824(1048576K)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,971 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Par Eden Space Heap memory: init = 83886080(81920K) used = 83886080(81920K) committed = 83886080(81920K) max = 83886080(81920K)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,971 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - Par Survivor Space Heap memory: init = 10485760(10240K) used = 10485760(10240K) committed = 10485760(10240K) max = 10485760(10240K)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,972 CassandraDaemon.java:503 - CMS Old Gen Heap memory: init = 922746880(901120K) used = 1966320(1920K) committed = 922746880(901120K) max = 922746880(901120K)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,976 CassandraDaemon.java:505 - Classpath: /apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/conf:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/build/classes/main:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/build/classes/thrift:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/airline-0.6.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/antlr-runtime-3.5.2.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-3.11.15.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/apache-cassandra-thrift-3.11.15.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/asm-5.0.4.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/caffeine-2.2.6.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/cassandra-driver-core-3.0.1-shaded.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/commons-cli-1.1.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/commons-lang3-3.1.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/commons-math3-3.2.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/compress-lzf-0.8.4.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/concurrentlinkedhashmap-lru-1.4.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/concurrent-trees-2.4.0.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/ecj-4.4.2.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/guava-18.0.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/high-scale-lib-1.0.6.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/hppc-0.5.4.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jackson-annotations-2.13.2.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jackson-core-2.13.2.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jackson-databind-2.13.2.2.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/javax.inject-1.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jbcrypt-0.4.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jctools-core-1.2.1.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jflex-1.6.0.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jna-4.2.2.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/joda-time-2.4.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/libthrift-0.9.2.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/logback-classic-1.2.9.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/logback-core-1.2.9.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/lz4-1.3.0.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/metrics-core-3.1.5.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/metrics-jvm-3.1.5.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/metrics-logback-3.1.5.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/ohc-core-0.4.4.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/ohc-core-j8-0.4.4.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/reporter-config3-3.0.3.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/reporter-config-base-3.0.3.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/sigar-1.6.4.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/snakeyaml-1.26.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/snappy-java-1.1.1.7.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/snowball-stemmer-1.3.0.581.1.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/ST4-4.0.8.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/stream-2.5.2.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/thrift-server-0.3.7.jar:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jsr223/*/*.jar::/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:36,976 CassandraDaemon.java:507 - JVM Arguments: [-Xloggc:/apps/opt/cassandra/logs/gc.log, -Dcassandra.replace_address=172.31.86.37, -ea, -XX:+UseThreadPriorities, -XX:ThreadPriorityPolicy=42, -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError, -Xss256k, -XX:StringTableSize=1000003, -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch, -XX:-UseBiasedLocking, -XX:+UseTLAB, -XX:+ResizeTLAB, -XX:+UseNUMA, -XX:+PerfDisableSharedMem, -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true, -XX:+UseParNewGC, -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled, -XX:SurvivorRatio=8, -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=1, -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75, -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly, -XX:CMSWaitDuration=10000, -XX:+CMSParallelInitialMarkEnabled, -XX:+CMSEdenChunksRecordAlways, -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled, -XX:+PrintGCDetails, -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps, -XX:+PrintHeapAtGC, -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution, -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime, -XX:+PrintPromotionFailure, -Xloggc:/apps/opt/cassandra/logs/gc.log, -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation, -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=10, -XX:GCLogFileSize=10M, -Xms979M, -Xmx979M, -Xmn100M, -XX:+UseCondCardMark, -XX:CompileCommandFile=/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/conf/hotspot_compiler, -javaagent:/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/jamm-0.3.0.jar, -XX:HeapDumpPath=/apps/opt/cassandra/logs/cassandra-1684768834-pid5323.hprof, -Dcassandra.jmx.local.port=7199, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false, -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file=/etc/cassandra/jmxremote.password, -Djava.library.path=/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/lib/sigar-bin, -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=kill -9 %p, -Dlogback.configurationFile=logback.xml, -Dcassandra.logdir=/apps/opt/cassandra/logs, -Dcassandra.storagedir=/apps/opt/cassandra/cassandra/data]
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:37,201 NativeLibrary.java:176 - JNA mlockall successful
WARN  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:37,202 StartupChecks.java:136 - jemalloc shared library could not be preloaded to speed up memory allocations
WARN  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:37,203 StartupChecks.java:169 - JMX is not enabled to receive remote connections. Please see cassandra-env.sh for more info.
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:37,205 SigarLibrary.java:44 - Initializing SIGAR library
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:37,234 SigarLibrary.java:180 - Checked OS settings and found them configured for optimal performance.
WARN  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:37,239 StartupChecks.java:311 - Maximum number of memory map areas per process (vm.max_map_count) 65530 is too low, recommended value: 1048575, you can change it with sysctl.
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:37,526 QueryProcessor.java:121 - Initialized prepared statement caches with 10 MB (native) and 10 MB (Thrift)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:38,809 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.IndexInfo
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:39,977 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.batches
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:39,997 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.paxos
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,029 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.local
INFO  [SSTableBatchOpen:1] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,086 BufferPool.java:251 - Global buffer pool is enabled, when pool is exhausted (max is 242.000MiB) it will allocate on heap
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,538 CacheService.java:103 - Initializing key cache with capacity of 48 MBs.
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,550 CacheService.java:125 - Initializing row cache with capacity of 0 MBs
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,557 CacheService.java:154 - Initializing counter cache with capacity of 24 MBs
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,558 CacheService.java:165 - Scheduling counter cache save to every 7200 seconds (going to save all keys).
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,592 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.peers
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,617 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.peer_events
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,666 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.range_xfers
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,687 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.compaction_history
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,719 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.sstable_activity
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,741 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.size_estimates
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,757 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.available_ranges
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,768 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.transferred_ranges
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,783 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.views_builds_in_progress
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,802 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.built_views
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,813 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.hints
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,830 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.batchlog
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,840 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.prepared_statements
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,852 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.schema_keyspaces
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,869 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.schema_columnfamilies
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,880 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.schema_columns
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,900 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.schema_triggers
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,910 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.schema_usertypes
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,926 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.schema_functions
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,938 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system.schema_aggregates
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:40,953 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system as storage service is not initialized
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,168 ApproximateTime.java:44 - Scheduling approximate time-check task with a precision of 10 milliseconds
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,230 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.keyspaces
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,262 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.tables
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,287 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.columns
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,313 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.triggers
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,338 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.dropped_columns
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,363 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.views
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,386 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.types
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,407 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.functions
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,423 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.aggregates
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,449 ColumnFamilyStore.java:432 - Initializing system_schema.indexes
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,466 ViewManager.java:137 - Not submitting build tasks for views in keyspace system_schema as storage service is not initialized
INFO  [ScheduledTasks:1] 2023-05-22 15:20:41,687 TokenMetadata.java:527 - Updating topology for all endpoints that have changed
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,102 StorageService.java:773 - Populating token metadata from system tables
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,180 StorageService.java:780 - Token metadata:
INFO  [pool-4-thread-1] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,343 AutoSavingCache.java:174 - Completed loading (6 ms; 4 keys) KeyCache cache
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,380 CommitLog.java:169 - Replaying /apps/opt/cassandra/data/commitlogs/CommitLog-6-1684768148735.log
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,438 CommitLog.java:171 - Log replay complete, 0 replayed mutations
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,439 StorageService.java:773 - Populating token metadata from system tables
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,471 StorageService.java:780 - Token metadata:
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,640 QueryProcessor.java:174 - Preloaded 0 prepared statements
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,647 StorageService.java:791 - Cassandra version: 3.11.15
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,648 StorageService.java:792 - Thrift API version: 20.1.0
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,648 StorageService.java:793 - CQL supported versions: 3.4.4 (default: 3.4.4)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,648 StorageService.java:795 - Native protocol supported versions: 3/v3, 4/v4, 5/v5-beta (default: 4/v4)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,716 IndexSummaryManager.java:87 - Initializing index summary manager with a memory pool size of 48 MB and a resize interval of 60 minutes
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,744 MessagingService.java:750 - Starting Messaging Service on /172.31.88.213:7000 (eth0)
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,777 StorageService.java:681 - Gathering node replacement information for /172.31.86.37
INFO  [main] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,824 OutboundTcpConnection.java:108 - OutboundTcpConnection using coalescing strategy DISABLED
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/172.31.86.170] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,857 OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with /172.31.86.170
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: Unable to gossip with any peers
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1603)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1526)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareForReplacement(StorageService.java:682)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:958)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:837)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:786)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:395)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:633)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786)
ERROR [main] 2023-05-22 15:21:43,862 CassandraDaemon.java:803 - Exception encountered during startup
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1603)
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper.doShadowRound(Gossiper.java:1526)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareForReplacement(StorageService.java:682)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.prepareToJoin(StorageService.java:958)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:837)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.StorageService.initServer(StorageService.java:786)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.setup(CassandraDaemon.java:395)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:633)
        at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.main(CassandraDaemon.java:786)
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-05-22 15:21:43,889 HintsService.java:210 - Paused hints dispatch
WARN  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-05-22 15:21:43,896 Gossiper.java:1728 - No local state, state is in silent shutdown, or node hasn't joined, not announcing shutdown
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-05-22 15:21:43,897 MessagingService.java:985 - Waiting for messaging service to quiesce
INFO  [ACCEPT-/172.31.88.213] 2023-05-22 15:21:43,898 MessagingService.java:1346 - MessagingService has terminated the accept() thread
INFO  [StorageServiceShutdownHook] 2023-05-22 15:21:44,203 HintsService.java:210 - Paused hints dispatch
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please do not just paste a "wall of text" and expect someone to sort it out for you.  We just need the _relevant_ part of the error message(s).  Secondly, make sure it's properly formatted.

Answer (score 2):

This is your issue:

```
INFO  [HANDSHAKE-/172.31.86.170] 2023-05-22 15:20:42,857 OutboundTcpConnection.java:561 - Handshaking version with /172.31.86.170
Exception (java.lang.RuntimeException) encountered during startup: Unable to gossip with any peers
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to gossip with any peers
```

172.31.86.170 is likely specified in your seed list and is not able to be reached.

I advise having a look through the [docs on replacing a node](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/operating/topo_changes.html#replacing-a-dead-node).  Specifically, to make sure that `-Dcassandra.replace_address_first_boot=<dead_node_ip>` is getting set in the `cassandra-env.sh`.

Also, it doesn't look like an IP address is being set for this node.  That's likely a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a networking issue. The new node cannot connect to the seed node you configured:

```
seed_provider=org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider{seeds=172.31.86.170}
```

You need to make sure that there is network connectivity between this node (`172.31.88.213`) and the seed node, making sure that there is bi-directional access on gossip port `7000`.

If there is a firewall between the nodes, you need to allow TCP traffic going both ways.

Also make sure that Cassandra is running on the seed node. If `172.31.86.170` is the dead node then you won't be able to use it as a seed so you have to pick another node. Cheers!